# Sending email from Email library in CodeIgniter takes too much time

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I don't know if anyone faced the same issue but it's taking too much time to send email from Email library provided by CodeIgniter. It almost takes 7-8 seconds per mail.

I tried with TLS (Microsoft), SSL(Google) but no changes in speed.

Thanks for anticipation.

Comment: That's because you're connecting to a remote server, authenticating, sending message, and closing the connection.

Comment: I misunderstand, why is 8 seconds a problem if you are only sending one email? How may emails do you want to send?

Comment: I want to send one email only but that is only taking like 7-8 seconds. I checked it using date(h:i:s) function and sending takes that much of time [$this->mail->send()].

Comment: It is not the transmitting (sending) of the email that takes the time. It is the 'conversations' between the various servers, and verifying whether you are authorised to send email via the server, that takes the time. **[This may help to understand the 'process'](http://www.aysoft.com/tips/email.htm)**.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent but how can I improve the speed? Is there any way to send mail faster?

Comment: I do not see how the process can be made faster. Why are you so concerned? I don't think anyone would mind waiting a few seconds for the email to be sent.

Comment: PHP Mail function is quick. It sends in a second but ends up in the SPAM folder. It might be sending so quick because it doesn't use SMTP.